# Code Analysis gives "Declare event handlers correctly" message

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, code-analysis

I just ran code analysis on my c# winforms project.
I get a warning

```
CA1009  Declare event handlers correctly    
Declare the second parameter of    'NameEditEx.TextChanged' as an EventArgs,
 or an instance of a type that extends EventArgs, named 'e'.
```

The class in question is in a user control containing the following;

```
    public delegate void TextChanged();

    [Browsable(true)]
    public event TextChanged OnTextChanged;
```

A form that has the control on it has the following code in InitializeComponent

```
 this.nameEditEx1.OnTextChanged += new NameEditExLib.NameEditEx.TextChanged(this.nameEditEx1_OnTextChanged);
```

The method is

```
    private void nameEditEx1_OnTextChanged()
    {
        try
        {
            UpdateName();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HandleException.Show(ex);
        }

    }
```

The code appears to be working fine when I run it.
Should I alter the code to get rid of the warning?
If so, how do I do that?

Update
 [Microsofts link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms182133.aspx)

Comment: This answer provides inside on this as well

[CA1009][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305861/ca1009-declare-event-handlers-correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The delegate should be

```
public delegate void TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

The method should be

```
private void nameEditEx1_OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Doing so ensures consistency for with other types of events where first argument is sender and second is EventArgs.

You can then invoke the event handler by calling

```
OnTextChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Comment: Should all delegates be declared this way or just some?  If just some, how do I tell which ones?

Comment: Delegates used for events should be declared this way. You can also replace the EventArgs with a class that inherits from EventArgs (e.g. the list here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.aspx#inheritanceContinued)

Comment: aren't all delegates used for events?

Comment: No. They can be used for callbacks, among other things. The following uses delegates for callback https://bitbucket.org/mattkotsenas/c-promises/src/229363cb9832b63c3a727d29c3d5a2b0e093ee3c/c-promises/Promise.cs?at=default

Comment: Please explain why they should have that pattern. And "that is the rule" as answer is not good enough, there must be some actual practical reason.

Comment: @NiKiZe By running code analysis, you have opted to follow the rules that comes with it. If you don't like this rule, you can suppress it.

Comment: So we have a pattern that has a rule, and everyone are saying to follow that pattern, but no-one can explain why that pattern is a pattern, and the only argument is that it is a pattern and nothing else?

Comment: @NiKiZe The reason is already stated: Doing so ensures consistency with other types of events where first argument is sender and second is EventArgs.

People value consistency a lot so that there are less things to remember.

Comment: That is a pattern do to pattern and not a real reason. (consistency is important, but can't be the only reason on it's own)
For example, why not have just eventargs and sender being part of eventargs.

Comment: @NiKiZe Because it allows micro-optimization by passing EventArgs.Empty, therefore no memory allocations are needed for the arguments, requiring only allocation for the event delegate itself. You probably enjoy reading up https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues. There are a lot of other strange designs that results from compromising on memory allocations and performance.