# Passing variables between classes in .net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I keep getting the following message when I run code analysis.

> CA1009 : Microsoft.Design : Declare the first parameter of 'xyz.EvaluateEventHandler' as an object named 'sender'
>
> CA1009 : Microsoft.Design : Declare the second parameter of 'xyz.EvaluateEventHandler' as an EventArgs, or an instance of a type that extends EventArgs, named 'e'

How do I pass the variables, but also include sender and e to fix this violation?

```
'xyx class
Public Event Evaluate(ByVal np As String, ByRef test As Boolean)
RaiseEvent Evaluate(Np, test)



'NpHandler class
AddHandler _xyx.Evaluate, AddressOf Evaluate
Private Sub Evaluate(ByVal np As String, ByRef test As Boolean)
Console.WriteLine(np)
Console.WriteLine(test)
End Sub
```

Comment: Event handler methods should not return a value. In the C# programming language, this is indicated by the return type void. 
To fix a violation of this rule, correct the signature, return type, or parameter names of the delegate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CA1009: Declare event handlers correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305861/ca1009-declare-event-handlers-correctly)

Comment: This is not C# and it is not a duplicate of  CA1009: Declare event handlers correctly.  Either way, thank you for the down vote!

Answer (score 3):

An event handler [by convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305861/ca1009-declare-event-handlers-correctly) accepts two parameters: a `sender` object and a parameter derived from `EventArgs`. That's what this code analysis rule is checking for. So your `Evaluate` event signature should look like this:

```
Public Event Evaluate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EvaluateEventArgs)
```

Your `EvaluateEventArgs` class could then contain the parameters you wish to pass to the listener.

```
Public Class EvaluateEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public Property Np As String
    Public Property Test As Boolean
End Class
```

You would then raise it as:

```
Dim args As New EvaluateEventArgs()
RaiseEvent Evaluate(Me, args)
'...check args.Np, args.Test here if desired
```

And your event listener declaration would be:

```
Private Sub Evaluate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EvaluateEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine(e.Np)
    Console.WriteLine(e.Test)
End Sub
```