# Declare callback event handlers correctly

Tags: c#, events, callback, delegates

I have a simple delegate, event and property allowing me to create callback subscriptions on events:

```
public static class Test
{
    /// <summary>Delegate for property changed event</summary>
    public delegate void TestEventHandler();

    /// <summary>Event called when value is changed</summary>
    public static event TestEventHandler OnTestHappening;

    /// <summary>Property to specify our test is happening</summary>
    private static bool testHappening;
    public static bool TestHappening
    {
        get
        {
            return testHappening;
        }
        set
        {
            testHappening = value;

            // Notify our value has changed only if True
            // ie. Only fire an event when we're ready as we'll hook methods to the Event that must only fire if ready
            if ( value )
            {
                if ( OnTestHappening != null )
                    OnTestHappening();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can then easily subscribe and unsubscribe to the event and fire the event callbacks as needed:

```
public class Tester
{
    private void Main()
    {
        Testing();

        // Start the test
        Test.TestHappening = true;
    }

    private void Testing()
    {
        // Unsubscribe from event
        Test.OnTestHappening -= Testing;

        // Check if we're busy testing yet
        if ( !Test.TestHappening )
        {
            // Subscribe to event
            Test.OnTestHappening += new Test.TestEventHandler( Testing );

            return;
        }

        // Do stuff here....
    }
}
```

When compiling, code analysis gives me, "CA1009: Declare event handlers correctly?" and I've searched high and low and found many questions, articles etc but none that feel like they address my scenario.  I can't seem to find a concrete starting point for the conversion and I'm starting to wonder if I'm meant to completely rewrite the implementation?

Edit: Firstly I really appreciate the assists, I did look carefully through all the sites I could before posting this and I did see (and try work with) each of the links that you all posted.  I even went back and studied delegates and events again but I feel like I'm missing the starting point somehow because each time I try change a part of it, I just keep producing errors that I can't come back from like:

```
public delegate void TestEventHandler( object sender, EventArgs e );
```

With the other links I visited, I could only find 1 similarity to my code (either in the delegate, the handler or the property) but couldn't find anything that related enough to mine to actually instil that "eureka" moment

Edit 2: I have now rebuilt my example with what "looks" to be the correct standard but this code is so fugly it looks like it was beaten with a confogulus stick and dipped in a tank of confutious before being deep fried in horriduculous:

```
public static class Test
{
    /// <summary>Delegate for property changed event</summary>
    public delegate void TestEventHandler( object sender, EventArgs e );

    /// <summary>Event called when value is changed</summary>
    public static event TestEventHandler OnTestHappening;

    /// <summary>Property to specify our test is happening</summary>
    private static bool testHappening;
    public static bool TestHappening
    {
        get
        {
            return testHappening;
        }
        set
        {
            testHappening = value;

            // Notify our value has changed only if True
            // ie. Only fire an event when we're ready as we'll hook methods to the Event that must only fire if ready
            if ( value )
            {
                if ( OnTestHappening != null )
                    OnTestHappening( null, EventArgs.Empty );
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Tester
{
    private void Main()
    {
        Testing( this, EventArgs.Empty );

        // Start the test
        Test.TestHappening = true;
    }

    private void Testing( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        // Unsubscribe from the event
        Test.OnTestHappening -= Testing;

        // Check if we're busy testing yet
        if ( !GlobalClass.SystemOnline )
        {
            // Subscribe to the event
            Test.OnTestHappening += new Test.TestEventHandler( Testing );

            return;
        }

        // Do stuff here....
    }
}
```

Please tell me I've missed something and that there is in fact a more elegant implementation

Edit 3 : Based on the code by Enigmativity, I've reworked the code to it's most basic form. I've also moved the code setting the variable to true in a different method so it doesn't look so daft sitting in `Main`.

```
public static class Test4
{
    /// <summary>Event called when value is changed</summary>
    public static event EventHandler TestHappening;

    /// <summary>Property to specify our test is happening</summary>
    private static bool test = false;
    public static bool Test
    {
        get
        {
            return test;
        }
        set
        {
            // Notify our value has changed only if True
            // ie. Only fire an event when we're ready as we'll hook methods to the Event that must only fire if ready
            if ( value )
            {
                TestHappening( null, EventArgs.Empty );
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Tester4
{
    private void Main()
    {
        Testing( this, EventArgs.Empty );
    }

    private void Testing( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        // Unsubscribe from the event
        Test4.TestHappening -= Testing;

        // Check if we're busy testing yet
        if ( !Test4.Test )
        {
            // Subscribe to the event
            Test4.TestHappening += Testing;

            return;
        }

        // Do stuff here....
    }

    private void SomeMethodCalledFromSomewhere()
    {
        // Set the value to true and thereby start the test
        Test4.Test = true;
    }
}
```

1. Would this be considered good code or should I rather have the `OnTestHappening` method as defined in Enigmativity's code?
2. Why can't I use a parameterless delegate?  It's now using the default `( object sender, EventArgs e )` but that feels overkill and doesn't make sense why the compiler is happy with it but according to coding standards it's considered bad code?  I'm not arguing the standard but rather trying to understand it's reasoning.

Comment: Did you read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182133.aspx ? In particular, look at the signature of your delegate...

Comment: You are registering an eventhandler that points to the current executing method. Is that correct? Don't you mean to register the method `Go` as eventhandler?

Comment: Please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27305925/7122

Comment: possible duplicate of [CA1009: Declare event handlers correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305861/ca1009-declare-event-handlers-correctly)

Comment: The simple solutions would be to rename `TestEventHandler` to something else (say) `TestHandler` and then the CA1009 test won't be performed.

Comment: Your naming conventions are wrong. `OnTestHappening` is usually the method that raises the event (not the event itself). The event itself would normally be called `TestHappening`.

Comment: @JonSkeet : That was the first one I checked after the initial [CA1009](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182133.aspx) page.  @Maarten : It's meant to allow a hook so that the method will be called back when the test happens. `Go` is purely to kick things off.  @DavidArno : I did check those answers before posting, thanks! @Uebercoder : So if I remove the word `Event` from the name the test won't be performed?

Comment: @Enigmativity : Would you be so kind as to elaborate please? `TestHappening` is the name of my property and `OnTestHappening` is the event that fires when it happens thus resulting in the callback.  Should I rather name the property `TestIsHappening`?

Comment: What method do you expect to be called though? You're unsubscribing from and resubscribing to the event *in the method that's handling the event*. Basically it's all very unclear what you're really trying to do, but yes, the warning was basically because you had the wrong delegate signature. (You don't need your own delegate at all for this - just use EventHandler.) If you want to ignore event conventions and use one with a different signature, that's up to you - but fundamentally the code analysis is doing exactly what it's meant to...

Comment: @JonSkeet - The reason the handler is unsubscribing is because (as far as I know) it's not possible to see whether a method is subscribed to an event.  So each time the method is called (can be numerous times and will also be once the event is raised) it unsubscribes itself to ensure it doesn't subscribe more than once

Comment: Well that's not thread-safe, to start with... and why would you not just subscribe once to start with? Basically you've got a very odd situation which you didn't mention at all in the question... That's not really relevant to the problem you're running into, which is that you're violating event conventions and then acting surprised that a convention-checking code analysis tool is complaining at you.

Comment: If you feel that you have no reason to pass along the sender and an empty `EventArgs` object, then don't, that's fine.  Obviously a tool designed to warn you of violation of MS's coding standards will warn you when you're not following those standards.  As long as you know that you're not following the standard and feel that your code is better when it doesn't, then that's your choice.  Stylistic choices are, by their nature, subjective.

Comment: @JonSkeet - When you're referring to "not thread-safe" are you referring to the fact that it's static?  It's meant to allow a single system wide implementation so that any thread can have itself called back when the test begins.  If I've missed something I'd appreciate your insight.  I apologise if I didn't clarify my question enough, I wasn't aware of the fact at the time of stating it; I was also not aware that I was violating event conventions, I (to the best of my knowledge) was thinking I was on the right track and was then surprised when CA complained and am trying to now understand it

Comment: @Storm: I'm talking about the situation where if you get multiple callbacks entering the method at the same time, the first one will unsubscribe, then all of them will resubscribe - so you end up with *lots* of subscriptions instead of one. It's still not at all clear why the handler would want to mess around with the subscriptions at all. Now that you know that it's violating the conventions, and how to fix that (basically, use `EventHandler`) I'm not sure what's left in the question.

Comment: @Servy - Thanks for your answer, I'm trying to make sure that I follow good coding standards and when I fail at it, I want to understand the reason for it so I don't make the mistake again.  Isolated developers like myself rely on the vast knowledge of yourselves so that as a community we all become better coders

Comment: @JonSkeet - Thanks Jon, my sole question remaining right now is really what the difference is between `public delegate void TestEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)` and `public delegate void TestEventHandler()` and why I can't use the latter according to the coding standard.  I fully understand it's saying I must use the former, but I don't understand why the latter is bad

Comment: @Storm: The answer is "the first is the convention for events, the second isn't." See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229011. It's only a convention - your code will still work if you violate it...

Comment: @JonSkeet - Wish I'd found your link during all my searching today. That makes so much sense now, thank you so much and sorry for the frustration, I understand now why you couldn't get my issue. I also now understand why Enigmativity's code looks the way it does.  If only I worked with guys like yourselves every day I'd also know something :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per Storm's request, here is how I would most likely structure the code. It's more inline with the standard conventions.

```
public static class TestClass
{
    public delegate void TestEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public static event TestEventHandler TestHappening;

    private static bool test = false;
    public static bool Test
    {
        get
        {
            return test;
        }
        set
        {
            test = value;
            if (test)
            {
                OnTestHappening();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OnTestHappening()
    {
        var handler = TestHappening;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

And `Tester` would look like this:

```
public class Tester
{
    public void Main()
    {
        TestClass.TestHappening += Testing;
        Go();
    }

    private void Testing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(TestClass.Test);
        TestClass.TestHappening -= Testing;
    }

    private void Go()
    {
        TestClass.Test = true;
    }
}
```

Calling it would look like this:

```
var tester = new Tester();
tester.Main();
```

Running this outputs `True` to the console.

---

If I were writing this in a more standard way, it would look like this:

```
public class TestEventArg : EventArgs
{
    public TestEventArg(bool updatedValue)
    {
        this.UpdatedValue = updatedValue;
    }
    public bool UpdatedValue { get; private set; }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public event EventHandler<TestEventArg> TestHappening;

    private bool test = false;
    public bool Test
    {
        get { return test; }
        set
        {
            var old = test;
            test = value;
            if (test != old)
                OnTestHappening(test);
        }
    }

    private void OnTestHappening(bool updatedValue)
    {
        var handler = TestHappening;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new TestEventArg(updatedValue));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, based on your code I was on the right track but now there's an additional method on top of the existing delegate, event and property?  This feels like overkill but I can definitely see the logic in terms of code maintenance and consistency.  I see you've also passed null as the `sender` since it's a static class, I was rather concerned about that one at first, is it correct to be passing null? I've also updated both my examples to be a little more clearer I hope

Comment: @Storm - The main point of doing this was to show the standard use for the name `OnTestHappening`. It's usually a protected method in a class to allow descendent classes to raise the event (only the class where the event is defined can raise the event - not even descendents can). The use of the standard event pattern in a `static` class is something that you might chose to avoid - in fact I don't think it is terribly useful in non-static classes. In your code I would redefine it as `public delegate void TestEventHandler();` and avoid the concern of what to pass.

Comment: @Storm - Also I based my code on **your** code. I don't think you can draw the conclusion that you were on the right track because of my code. I tried to adapt your code to be more inline with the standard conventions by making **minimal** changes to your code. Don't draw the wrong conclusions.

Comment: @Storm - I've added a more standard solution. In this case it is up to the consumer to ignore the `False` values - as it should be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code, it really helps to work through something when you have a basis to work from.  My biggest question right now, is why do we need to use a delegate with a `sender` and `EventArgs` `public delegate void TestEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)` when the original works just fine `public delegate void TestEventHandler()` since we're never interested in the `sender` or the `EventArgs`?

Comment: Thanks so much, between you, Jon Skeet and Servy I am able to not only correct the code but also understand why it needs to be the way it is