# Do not nest type warning (C#)

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have the following code in a class to setup a serial port even handler.

I get two warnings; CA1034 (Do not nest types), which tells me to make my delgate private (which will stop me being to setup the even handler in inherited classes), and CA1009 (declare the second parameter of the event as an EventArgs, or a instance of a type that extends EventArgs, named 'e'), which I don't understand.

My code is below

```
myPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_OnDataRecived); //Setup when port is opened

private void port_OnDataRecived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
        int lengthToRead = myPort.BytesToRead;
        byte[] rxBytes = new byte[lengthToRead];
        myPort.Read(rxBytes, 0, lengthToRead);
        PacketReceived(rxBytes, e);
}

public delegate void PacketReceivedEventHandler(object sender, byte[] packet);
public event PacketReceivedEventHandler OnPacketReceived;

public virtual void PacketReceived(byte[] packet, EventArgs e)
{
        if (OnPacketReceived != null)
        {
            OnPacketReceived(this, packet);                
        }
}
```

I have been looking at MSDN articles and some SO questions, but I can't relate the suggested fixes back to my own code.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305861/ca1009-declare-event-handlers-correctly) sort of makes sense, but converting my code to look like it leads to

```
OnPacketReceived(this, packet);
```

being replaced with

```
handle(this, new PacketReceivedEventHandler();
```

which takes an argument `(void (object, byte[]) target)` (that's where I get stuck). As for trying to fix the CA1034 warning I don't even see how what I have written is a nested type and the MSDN article doesn't contain a example of how to fix the rule violation.

Comment: Try by removing the delegate and the event and using an `EventArgs<PacketReceivedEventArgs>` where `PacketReceivedEventArgs` is a class that extends `System.EventArgs` and contains properties for the information you need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't even see how what I have written is a nested type

You've declared your delegate type (`PacketReceivedEventHandler`) within your class. That's one type nested inside another. Just move the declaration outside your existing class declaration.

For the other warning, you'd want to create a `PacketEventArgs` class deriving from `EventArgs` and containing the packet data as an extra property. At that point, you could use an `EventHandler<PacketEventArgs>` and not declare your own delegate at all.

Additionally:

- Your current way of checking handler nullity is broken as it could change from being non-null to null between calls.
- Normally the event would be called `PacketReceived` and your method would be `OnPacketReceived` (and protected), rather than the other way round.

With all this in place, you'd have:

```
public event EventHandler<PacketEventArgs> PacketReceived;

protected virtual void OnPacketReceived(byte[] packet)
{
    var handler = PacketReceived;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler.Invoke(this, new PacketEventArgs(packet));
    }
}
```

Or in C# 6, using the null conditional operator to make the implementation simpler:

```
public event EventHandler<PacketEventArgs> PacketReceived;

protected virtual void OnPacketReceived(byte[] packet)
{
    PacketReceived?.Invoke(this, new PacketEventArgs(packet));
}
```

Comment: PacketEventArgs would be the class that implements EventArgs? That would take a byte[] as an argument.
I'm trying to work out how to change the SerialDataReceivedEventHandler as `PacketReceived(rxBytes, e)` no longer takes a SerialDataReceivedEventHandler as an argument.

Comment: @Mike159: Well, it would derive from `EventArgs`, yes. From `port_OnDataRecived` you'd call `OnPacketReceived(txBytes)`.

Comment: How do I then set up the even outside the class? With delegates it is `Class.Event += new Class.Delegate(methodToGoTo);` but the delegate no longer exists.

Comment: @Mike159: Well I'd use a method group conversion, so just `Class.Event += methodToInvoke;`. But if you *want* to use the C# 1 syntax, you'd use `Class.Event += new EventHandler<PacketEventArgs>(methodToInvoke);`. It sounds like you could do with reading http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx

Comment: Using `Class.Event += methodToInvoke;` how do I pass the byte array to my method?
Clearly I do need to read that article...

Comment: @Mike159: That's just the subscription to the event. That's not actually *invoking* the method - that happens when the event is raised. Yes, I strongly suggest you read my article or another on event handling basics - I think you're a bit confused about how it all fits together at the moment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99953/discussion-between-mike159-and-jon-skeet).

Comment: I think the point I am getting stuck at is `PacketReceived?.Invoke(this, new PacketEventArgs(packet));`

Outside of the class how to I actually access the packet? The original delegate method assigned a method to the event which is called when data is received (the packet is then passed to be used). Now I can't assign my method because it is expecting a byte array when it is being assigned.

Comment: @Mike159: Outside the class, you would have an event handler which would receive the `PacketEventArgs`, (as the second parameter) and then access the `Data` property (or whatever) you'd add to `PacketEventArgs`. You'll need to change the method you're subscribing with to have an appropriate signature.

Comment: Thanks. Now it compiles and I can step through it this method makes a lot more sense.